# "..profit from burgers is more than offset by the damage..." how to understand this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

"To help quantify the costs of a poor diet, I recently tried to estimate this impact in terms of a most famous food, the burger. **I concluded that the profit from burgers is more than offset by the damage they cause in health problems and environmental harm.**"

I found this sentence from a passage in which the writer encourages people to cook.

My questions are:

1. is "offset" a verb here? If so, how to understand the function of "more than"?
2. which two things are compared, *the profit* and *offset* or *the profit* and *the damage*?
3. *profit* here means *the advantage or benefit that is gained from doing sth*, not something finical or economical, right?

Please help~

Comment: 1. I don't think so. I'd call it an adjective (serving in a prepositional phrase complement to *more*, which is a predicate complement, i.e., *profit* = *more*). 2. The comparison is between profit and damage. Offset is the measure of the comparison. 3. Yes. *What profiteth it a man to consume a burger every day and die young of heart disease because of it?*

Comment: Thanks deadrat. But I still find it difficult to understand. It seems that the profit somehow overweights the damage. However, the author hates burger. He has a negative attitude towards fast foods. Why would he say the profit is more than the damage? :( so confused

Comment: Think about weighing the benefits and detriments of burgers on a scale. We'll put *tastes good* on the benefit side; cost (say, this is fast food) on the detriment side. And let's say these balance. We say that the benefits (or profits) are exactly offset by the costs (or detriments). Now we add the health problems to the detriment side and the scale tips to the bad. We say that the profits are more than offset by the costs, i.e, the costs outweigh the benefits. Tell me if that's clear.

Comment: deadrat, you're awesome!!! This sentence is crystal clear to me now. A million thanks. ;)